# Using _flushall() repaired my code, and I don't understand why

Tags: c, string, visual-studio, buffer

I wrote a function that removes a given `char` from a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* input_long(void);
void removeChar(char str[], char ch);

void main()
{       
 char *str, ch;

 str=input_long();
 printf("\nplease enter a char to be removed from the string: ");
 scanf("%c", &ch);

 removeChar(str, ch);
 printf("the string after the removal is %s \n", str);

 free(str);
}

void removeChar(char str[], char ch) //this function removing a given char from a given string//
{
 int i,j = 0;
 for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) //looping the string until its end//
     {
     if (str[i] != ch) //by that we ensure the char will be erased from the string //
      {
       str[j] = str[i];
       j++;
      }
     }
  str[j]='\0';   //the end of the new string after the whole process//
}

char* input_long(void) //this function gets a string dynamically allocated//
{
 char tempstr[80], *str;

 printf("enter a string\n");
 gets(tempstr);
 str=(char*)malloc((strlen(tempstr)+1)*sizeof(char));
 strcpy(str,tempstr);

 return str;
}
```

My code didn't run well; when I ran it, it seemed to lead the statement which asks the user to enter a string. I repaired the code by adding  `_flushall()`  , and now the code is running well:

```
_flushall
 str=input_long();
 printf("\nplease enter a char to be removed from the string: ");
 scanf("%c", &ch);
```

I don't really understand why adding that statement indeed repaired it.

Comment: Don't use `gets()` ever. It is no longer a part of the C language for a reason. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: but that's what the teacher learned me...

Comment: "it seemed to lead the statement " --> What is "it"?  Is this the entire code or part of larger code?  `_flushall` --> Did you mean something else like `_flushall();`?  Post true code.

Comment: Did you add `_flushall()`, or `_flushall`? You have both in your question. In either case, where is it defined?

Comment: flushall(), of course....sorry...

Comment: when I run the code before adding that statement, I coudl not enter a string (the input).

Comment: @TOM1994 Again, is this your entire true code that shows the problem?

Comment: @cucx  part of code.

Comment: The problem is in the code not posted.

Comment: may you explain it to me?

Comment: please help me...

Comment: @TOM1994-- your code runs fine without the `_flushall()` for me. Are you running from the command-line, or from an IDE?

Comment: what do you mean? I have VS 2012

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE (integrated development environment). I don't work with Windows, so this is conjecture, but I would guess that Visual Studio is interfering with the output from your program. `_flushall()` writes any data that is in an output stream buffer to the appropriate locations. You can probably get the same effect by calling the standard, and portable, `fflush(stdout)`, which only flushes the `stdout` stream. If you can compile your program and run it from the command-line (in a terminal window), I am guessing that it will work without the `_flushall()`.

Comment: I added a Visual Studio tag; now maybe someone who knows more about this can weigh in.